# Mapping user users inside an Ubuntu-hosted Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I can't set up the docker container properly for my php/mysql project, I always get some problem about user permission.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
    services:
    web:
        image: jakubboucek/lamp-devstack-php:debug
    environment:
        APP_DEBUG: 1
        TZ: Europe/Prague
        PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=docker-cli"
        XDEBUG_CONFIG: "client_host=host.docker.internal"
        # APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: "/var/www/html/www"
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:8080:80"
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ".:/var/www/html"

    mysqldb:
        image: jakubboucek/lamp-devstack-mysql
    environment:
        MARIADB_DATABASE: default
        MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: devstack
        TZ: Europe/Prague
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:33060:3306"
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - "./.docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql"
```

> By `docker compose up` command will download the dependencies of this `.yml`

Here is my `Dockerfile` with which I want to reconfigure an existing container:

```
FROM jakubboucek/lamp-devstack-php:debug

RUN groupadd -g $(id -u) docker \
    && useradd -r -u $(id -u) -g docker dockeruser

USER dockeruser
```

I run the build: `docker build -t <container name> .`

Result of `stat` command of my project root:

```
File: .
Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 820h/2080d      Inode: 100717      Links: 12
Access: (2777/drwxrwsrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/pfort1990)   Gid: ( 1001/  docker)
Access: 2023-12-03 16:35:36.518448587 +0100
Modify: 2023-12-03 16:34:31.853631232 +0100
Change: 2023-12-03 16:34:31.853631232 +0100
Birth: 2023-11-20 20:45:04.900613275 +0100
```

And here result of `ls -la .` command inside project root:

```
total 160
drwxrwsrwx 12 pfort1990 docker  4096 Dec  3 16:34 .
drwxrwsr-x  5 pfort1990 docker  4096 Dec  3 12:40 ..
drwxrwsrwx  3 pfort1990 docker  4096 Oct 28 19:08 .docker
drwxrwsrwx  7 pfort1990 docker  4096 Dec  3 13:13 .git
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pfort1990 docker   116 Nov 21 19:07 .gitignore
drwxrwsrwx  3 pfort1990 docker  4096 Nov 21 21:26 .idea
drwxrwsrwx  9 pfort1990 docker  4096 Nov 21 21:08 App
-rw-r--r--  1 pfort1990 docker   720 Dec  3 16:20 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--  1 pfort1990 docker   517 Dec  3 15:39 Dockerfile_puvodni
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pfort1990 docker  1088 Oct 28 19:02 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx  1 pfort1990 docker 87748 Oct 28 19:02 composer.lock
drwxrwsrwx  4 pfort1990 docker  4096 Nov  5 21:21 content
-rw-r--r--  1 pfort1990 docker   616 Dec  3 16:25 docker-compose.yml
drwxrwsrwx  2 pfort1990 docker  4096 Oct 28 19:11 log
drwxrwsrwx  5 pfort1990 docker  4096 Nov  5 20:58 temp
drwxrwsrwx  3 pfort1990 docker  4096 Oct 28 19:02 tests
drwxrwsrwx 15 pfort1990 docker  4096 Oct 28 19:21 vendor
drwxrwsrwx  7 pfort1990 docker  4096 Oct 28 19:02 www
```

I did the initial configuration according to the docker documentation, such as assigning the directory with the project to the `docker` group and also added my user account to the `docker` user group.

Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? The Docker documentation is very extensive where I couldn't find any solutions. Thank you all.

Comment: Just run container with the same UID as you have in your local machine